# Where to look for PostgreSQL sock file on Centos 6.4?

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails

I installed postgresql9.1 into my Centos 6.4. I can do `psql template` (as `root`) to open the database console but cannot use Rails `rake db:create` to create the database:
`FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "root"`

My configuration is as follow:

```
{
"adapter"=>"postgresql", 
"host"=>"localhost", 
"encoding"=>"unicode", 
"username"=>"root", 
"pool"=>5, 
"database"=>"xxx_prod"
}
```

I guess Rails is unable to locate the sock file (.s.PGSQL.5432). So I would like to specify it explicitly but I don't know where the sock file is located. Where should it be? How can I locate it?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not the sock file, but the (very bad in my opinion) decision to make "ident" default authentication scheme.

Locate pg_hba.conf file and change "ident" into "trust" or "md5".

If you want to know more - consider reading [this blogpost](http://www.depesz.com/2007/10/04/ident/).

Comment: Please add the relevant contents instead of self-promoting your blog without disclosure.

Comment: After reading some of your posts, I am convinced of their value to the community; if you copy the relevant contents into the answer, you will remove a single-point-of-failure if your blog goes down. (Yes, there's also the Wayback Machine, but we shouldn't rely on it either).

Comment: What about - when SO will go down? My blog is online longer than SO. The relevant part is already in answer - find pg_hba.conf, and change authentication scheme.

Comment: So when I do `psql template1`, what kind of authentication is being used?

Comment: We can't know. You have to check in your pg_hba.conf file.